# Getting htmlreg tables side by side instead of stacked in rmarkdown

Tags: r, regression, r-markdown, texreg

I currently have three tables of regression output that I'm using htmlreg to create in R Markdown, but the default obviously is to just stack all three on top of each other if all 3 lines of code are in the same code chunk (or consecutive code chunks). I'm wondering if there is an easy way to get them all placed next to each other side-by-side.

Here is my current code, not that it will be particularly interesting in answering this question:

```
htmlreg(reg_b1, star.symbol = "\\*", doctype = FALSE, caption = "Figure 1.")
htmlreg(reg_b2, star.symbol = "\\*", doctype = FALSE, caption = "Figure 2.")
htmlreg(reg_b3, star.symbol = "\\*", doctype = FALSE, caption = "Figure 3.")
```